# Which deities grant the pride domain?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, religions-and-deities

The pride domain appears in the D&D 3.5 Spell Compendium, but does not list any gods that grant it. Does anyone know of an official source with any gods with this domain?

I've read in some places that Wee Jas will, but cannot find an official reference.

Comment: It's important to remember that Clerics don't have to have a deity, they can simply have "ideals" if you can't find one that "jives" with what you're going for. @Hey-I-Can-Chan's answer addresses your question I just wanted to give you another angle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although 2nd-party, according to Hal Maclean's article "Seven Deadly Domains: Spells for Sinners" (*Dragon* #323 62-6) the pride Domain is available from the following gods.

**Core**

- Bahamut
- Beltar
- Corellon Larethian
- Heironeous
- Hextor
- Iuz
- Lolth
- Moradin
- Pelor
- Pholtus
- Tiamat
- Vecna
- Wastri
- Wee Jas

**Eberron**

- Dol Arrah
- il-Yannah
- the Mockery
- Onatar

**Forgotten Realms**

- Bane
- Cyric
- Dumathoin
- Finder Wyvernspur
- Gargauth
- Gond
- Helm
- Horus-Re
- Kiaransalee
- Nobanion
- Oghma
- Osiris
- Set
- Shar
- Shevarash
- Siamorphe
- Sune
- Tempus
- Torm
- Tyr
- Ubatao
- Umberlee
- Velsharoon
- Vhaeraun
- Waukeen