# How can one avoid death by the Massive Damage rule using mundane methods?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

*Disclaimer: a previous question already covers [Arcane and Divine Spells vs Massive Damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/arcane-and-divine-spells-vs-massive-damage), so let us concentrate on more mundane ways.*

[Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8610/hey-i-can-chan) suggested that a handful of feats eliminated the need for Massive Damage saving throws altogether, while there were a couple of semi-mundane ways to avoid automatically failing a save when rolling a 1.

What are those mysterious ways to avoid death by the Massive Damage rule?

---

*Note: I personally know of the* Steadfast Determination *feat to avoid failing a* Fortitude *save when rolling a 1.*

*Note: Debating the merits of the rule itself is done [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72147/is-the-massive-damage-rule-needed), if you are interested.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here's a start

- The ancestor feat **Hardy Soul** (*Dragon* #315 64) has no prerequisites and, among other benefits, renders the creature immune to death from massive damage. As a Kara-Tur ancestor feat, it must be taken at level 1, and a creature can have only one ancestor feat.
- The untyped feat **Stoic Composure** (*Dragon* #284 123) has as prerequisites a Constitution of at least 13 and the feats [Endurance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#endurance) and [Toughness](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#toughness) and, among other benefits, renders the creature immune to death from massive damage.
- The general feat **Tomb-born Fortitude** (*Libris Mortis* 30) has as prerequisites a nongood alignment and the feat Tomb-tainted Soul (*LM* 31) and, among other benefits, renders the creature immune to death from massive damage.
- The general feat **Steadfast Determination** (*PH2* 83) has as its prerequisite [Endurance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#endurance) and, while it doesn't grant immunity to death from massive damage, in addition to other benefits, the creature no longer automatically fails Fortitude saving throws on a natural 1.
- The **granted power of the domain [Pride](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/35270/8610)** (*Spell Compendium* 278-9), like the above feat, doesn't make a creature immune to death from massive damage but, instead, allows rerolling natural 1s on saving throws. However, the creature *must* take the second result even if it's another 1. (How to get a domain's granted power without being a cleric is beyond this question's scope.)

Undoubtedly there are others.

Comment: It's *almost* not worth mentioning, but it may be useful for a DM's monsters: a creature *can* simply *double* its death-from-massive-damage threshold by taking the variant feat Resist Death (*Epic Level Handbook* 111), and the feat can be taken multiple times. However, its prerequisite of 21+ Hit Dice makes it unavailable to most PCs until epic levels despite the feat not being technically in the epic category.